# Vaadin with Bean Validator?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

Eclipse Kepler
Vaadin7

I'm adding the hibernate-validator-4.2.0.Final.jar in my build path but doesn't work. When I try use annotations in my bean doesn't work and not have auto complete.

Any idea ?

Comment: Could you please be more specific? Perhaps post your project tree?

Comment: I added bean-validator.jar and now works...thanks !

Comment: OK. Please do not forget to mark your question solved so others can see that this is no longer an open issue.

Comment: @FernandoPaiva Please post your solution as an answer and then click the green checkmark to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I added bean-validator.jar and now works.